# Determining proximity between 2 words in a sentence in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, nltk

I need to determine proximity between 2 words in a sentence in Python. For example, in the following sentence :

```
the foo and the bar is foo bar
```

I want to determine the distance between the words `foo` and  `bar` (determine number of words occurring between `foo` and  `bar`).

Please note that there are multiple occurrences of the words `foo` and  `bar` in the above sentence producing different distance combinations.

Also, order of the words shouldn't matter.  What is the best way to determine the distance between these words?

Here is the code I am using :

```
sentence = "the foo and the bar is foo bar"

first_word_to_look = 'foo'
second_word_to_look = 'bar'

first_word = 0
second_word = 0
dist = 0

if first_word_to_look in sentence and second_word_to_look in sentence:

    first_word = len(sentence.split(first_word_to_look)[0].split())
    second_word = len(sentence.split(second_word_to_look)[0].split())

    if first_word < second_word:
        dist = second_word-first_word
    else:
        dist = first_word-second_word

print dist  # distance
```

The problem with the above code is that it only considers first occurrences of both the words. If there are more occurrences in same sentence that are even closer than first one, it doesn't consider it.

What is the best way to determine the proximity ? Is there any library in python that can do this job better ?

Comment: Do you want to find the *minimum* distance between the two words, which in this case is 0?

Comment: @ mooiamaduck, yes ideally want to find the minimum distance between the two words. The problem is that there are multiple occurrences of the words foo and bar in the above sentence producing different distance combinations. So, if I can also get an average distance (along with minimum) it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your sentence to list of words and use `index` method of `list`:

```
sentence = "the foo and the bar is foo bar"
words = sentence.split()

def get_distance(w1, w2):
     if w1 in words and w2 in words:
          return abs(words.index(w2) - words.index(w1))
```

Update to count all word occurrences:

```
import itertools

def get_distance(w1, w2):
    if w1 in words and w2 in words:
        w1_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(words) if value == w1]    
        w2_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(words) if value == w2]    
        distances = [abs(item[0] - item[1]) for item in itertools.product(w1_indexes, w2_indexes)]
        return {'min': min(distances), 'avg': sum(distances)/float(len(distances))}
```

Comment: @ Eugene Soldatov, please note that there are multiple occurrences of the words foo and bar in the above sentence producing different distance combinations. Your code doesn't consider the closest one which is "foo bar" (last 2 words in the sentence). Your code is almost doing the same thing that my code above does.

Comment: @ Eugene Soldatov, thanks ! It worked like a charm :) If I can also get an average distance (along with minimum distance that you have solved) it would solve the problem.

Comment: @ Eugene Soldatov, Perfect  ! Thank you.

Comment: note: it doesn't matter in this case because number of words in a sentence is usually small but in general, both `w in words` and `words.index(w)` are `O(n)` in time operations. You might need to preprocess `words`, to get a better asymptotic complexity.

Comment: How to handle if there is multi-words? Any idea?
sentence = "You can split your sentence to list of words"
w1 = "you can"
w2 = "of words"

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expression as well. Following line will return a list, with
number of words occurring in between foo and bar

```
import re
sentence = "the foo and the bar is foo bar"
first_word_to_look = 'foo'
second_word_to_look = 'bar'
word_length = [len(i.split())-2 for i in re.findall(r'foo.*?bar',sentence)]
print word_length
```