# Python - Create key value pairs from multiple token keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, keyvaluepair

I have a dictionary that contains entries with a multitude of different keys and values.

Some multi-token strings delimited by spaces, some single token strings with no spaces.

Some line up exactly, keys with one token, values with one token:

```
"'Apl'": "'Apple'",
```

Some have single token keys and multiple token values:

```
"'Blpepr'": "'Bell Pepper'",
```

Some have multiple token keys and single token values:

```
"'Grn Bn'": "'Greenbean'",
```

and still others have multiple token keys and multiple token values (not always the same number on both sides!):

```
"'Swt Ptto'": "'Sweet Potato'",
```

I am trying to create a dictionary that assigns key:value pairs as closely as possible to their corresponding sides, such that at least I can get:

```
"'Apl'": "'Apple'",
"'Swt'": "'Sweet'",
"'Ptto'": "'Potato'",
```

I've considered the keys and values with numbers of tokens that don't match up to be a lost cause, since it's not readily possible to determine where a token begins and ends without a space. But at least with ones that are space delimited, we know where the tokens begin and end, so I'd like for the result to be similar to the above.

To retrieve only those keys with spaces, I've done the following to my dictionary:

```
for key, value in dictionary1.items():
    if " " in key and value:
        print(key + ":" + value)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably took the part *assigns key:value pairs as closely* very lightly. In order to train your system to identify the closeness by its own, you have to make neural network with training data. The easy but less precise approach (which I think you want) will be to check the count of occurrence of each character in order and map the value with maximum count

Comment: I think you should consider a word proximity algorithm. Take a look at [one answer implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33389155/835591)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` instead of how you currently are checking for spaces:

```
for x in old_dict:
    for i in range(0,2):
        key = x.split()[i]
        value = old_dict[x][0].split()[i]
        new_dict[key] = value
```